# kein Menschen/Mensch

Tags: grammatical-number, weak-declension

Ich habe hier ein Problem. Kann jemand es mir bitte erklären?

> Kein Fenster war erleuchtet, die Tür war verschlossen, sie sahen **keinen** Mensch**en**!

Ich dachte, *keinen Mensch* ist richtig, aber die Antwort war *keinen Menschen*.

Ist *Menschen* nicht Plural? Warum *keinen Menschen*?

Answer (score 11):

No, "Menschen" is not plural in your example.

It is accusative singular, thus "Menschen".

And if it *were* plural, "kein" would need to reflect that as well, like in

> Kein Fenster war erleuchtet, die Tür war verschlossen, sie sahen keine Menschen!

Answer (score 11):

Korrekt ist

> Sie sahen kein**en** Mensch**en**.

Jedoch gibt es im allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch auch die **grammatikalisch falsche** Variante, bei Nomen, die eigentlich [schwach flektiert](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Adjektiv/Deklinationstyp/Schwankend.html) würden, die Endung im Dativ und Akkusativ wegzulassen:

> Sie sahen kein**en** Mensch.

Ein anderes Beispiel ist das Nomen **der Bär**.

Richtig ist

> Sie sahen kein**en** Bär**en**. (Akk.)
>
> Sie gaben dem Bär**en** Honig. (Dat.)

Aber viele verwenden in der Umgangssprache

> Sie sahen keinen Bär. (Akk.)
>
> Sie gaben dem Bär Honig. (Dat.)

Comment: Das scheint aber regional unterschiedlich zu sein. Die Varianten »Sie sahen keinen Mensch«, »Sie sahen keinen Bär« und »Sie gaben dem Bär Honig« sind im Osten Österreichs nicht gebräuchlich.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Ich wohne im Osten Österreichs. Sätze wie "Hast du den **Herr** dort drüben gesehn?" hört man nicht zu selten in Wien/Niederösterreich.

Comment: Darf man fragen, wo genau du das gehört hast? Ich habe 30 Jahre lang in Graz gelebt (die gesamte Verwandtschaft lebt in der Oststeiermark), dann 20 Jahre lang in Wien und seit 3 Jahren wohne ich in St.Pölten. Aber »Hast du den Herr dort drüben gesehn?« ist mir noch nie aufgefallen.

Comment: "grammatikalisch falsch" ist ein starkes Statement. Auf welche Autorität berufst du dich dabei? Es ist enorm verbreitet (à la "Fahrscheine gibt's am Fahrscheinautomat"), und zumindest für _niemand_ nennt der Duden auch die Endungslose Flexion als korrekt: https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/Deklination-von-niemand

Answer (score -2):

> Sind "Menschen" nicht plural?

Ja. Aber dann würde der Satz "... sie sahen kein**e** Menschen" heißen.
Die Deklination von "Mensch" ist in allen vier Fällen "Menschen", sowohl im Singular als auch im Plural.
Siehe z.B. [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Mensch_Lebewesen_Individuum)

Comment: *Sie sahen keine Menschen* would be plural. *Sie sahen keinen Menschen* is singular.

Comment: Nein, in dem betreffenden Beispiel ist _Menschen_ nicht Plural.

Comment: In the sentence it’s singular, but *Menschen* can be singular or plural, depending on the case. I think this is what you mean, but maybe you could make it a bit more clear. That would, if the voter is still around, probably remove the -1 from your answer.